# Programming language for modular arithmetic over large numbers

Tags: implementation, modular-arithmetic, factoring

I'am trying to implement algorithms on integer factorization.This involves dealing with integers of 200-500 digits and doing modular arithmetic over them.Which programming language has inbuilt support for large numbers?Does C++ support large number arithmetic?

Comment: This question is not on topic here. By the way programming languages as python, ruby and many others have a inbuilt support for big numbers arithmetics. If you want still stick to C/C++ you can easily use a bignumber library (gmp for example)

Comment: Java also supports modular arithmetic over large numbers through the [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

Comment: It's better to use dedicated library as GMP Bignum. take a look at: https://gmplib.org/
Good Look, and don't forget to inform us on your work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming (languages). It would be more adequate for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) is another c++ bignum library, easier to use than GMP since it overloads the commonly used +,-,%,* operators.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 1) a programming problem, not a crypto problem. 2) A recommendation question with many possible answers, and thus not suitable for stackoverflow either.

Comment: Most major languages either ship with built in bigintegers or have third party implementations. I've heard good things about NTL and it has the additional advantage that it's not merely a biginteger library but contains support for a lot of advanced mathematical features that are useful for cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

Yours is a perfectly legitimate question.

I know that C#, F#, Java and Scala have an in-built support to handle arbitrarily large numbers, i.e. as large as your computer’s memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries that allow you to do that in almost any language.

There is BigInt/BigInteger class for Java/Scala. (The Scala's class is sjust a wrapper around the Java class.)

Haskell has type `Integer`. Do not confuse it with `Int`, which is for small numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is off-topic, I'll mention that depending on which factoring  algorithms you want to implement, the ablity to work with integers of arbitrary sizes may not be sufficient. For example, the sieving algorithms require the ability to do some linear algebra over finite fields, and the Quadratic/Number Field sieves require the ability to work in quadratic fields or even arbitrary number fields, respectively.

Unless you want to implement all of this from scratch, you will need to work in a CAS designed with number-theoretic applications in mind, such as Pari/GP or Sage. I have [blogged](http://blog.fkraiem.org/2013/12/07/factoring-integers-fermat-and-kraitchik/) [a](http://blog.fkraiem.org/2013/12/07/factoring-integers-factor-bases/) [little](http://blog.fkraiem.org/2013/12/08/factoring-integers-dixons-algorithm/) about sieving algorithms and their implementation in Sage, though I stopped before QS/NFS (and maybe I should continue sometime...).